# Is it a simplest substring in python?

Tags: python, string

Below is my code which get code(always in brackets, and always has 3 chars) from string :

```
raw_text='Spain (BCN)' #another examples: 'Italy (BGN)' , 'Germany (SXF)'
formatted_text=raw_text[raw_text.index('(')+1:len(raw_text)-1] # BCN,BGN,SFX
```

Can I write it simpler?

Comment: You can also use a regular expression....so check the docs of the 're' module...it is regular expression basics...

Comment: @Comrade Quacker: The second line is bloated.

Comment: @Duck: Confusing "number of lines" with "simplicity of code" is the root cause of some of the ugliest code you'll ever see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are certain to have this format why not just use:

```
s.strip()[-4: -1]
```

Of course, it does not check the format of your string. If you want to do that, use the re module (regular expressions).

Hope this helps,

Dimi

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
raw_text='Spain (BCN)'
formatted_text = re.search(r"""
    (?<=\() # assert that the preceding character is a (
    \w{3}   # match three alphanumeric characters
    (?=\))  # assert that the following character is a )""", 
    raw_text, re.VERBOSE).group(0)
```

would be another way of doing it (with a regular expression).

Comment: regex is definitly the way to go in this case

Comment: This may be more generic, but if his input text is strictly as he's specified it, this isn't exactly simpler.  Avoiding lookahead/lookbehind would help--they're so rarely used that most people have to look them up.  `re.search(r"\((.{3})\)", text).group(1)`

Comment: @Glenn: I would say that I use lookahead/lookbehind pretty much every single day. That’s not a rare usage.

Comment: @tchrist: Most people certainly don't.

Answer (score 1):

Yip there sure is.

```
raw_text='Spain (BCN)  '
print raw_text.rstrip(" ")[-4:-1]
```

Use rstrip to remove trailing spaces, eg trim.
Then simply go back 4 chars, to -1 chars.

Answer (score 1):

splicing a string is `[start:stop]` and you are stopping on `len(raw_text)-1` - always the second-last character.  If you know the code continues to the end of the string, and as you've said it is always three characters long, then:

```
 formatted_text=raw_text[-4:-1]
```

will extract the three characters that start 4 from the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> raw_text='Spain (BCN)'
>>> formatted_text=raw_text[raw_text.index('(')+1:len(raw_text)-1]
>>> formatted_text
'BCN'
>>> raw_text[raw_text.index('(')+1:-1]
'BCN'
>>>
```

What an allegedly non-brittle does:

```
>>> str = 'abcdefgh'
>>> str[str.find('(')+1:str.find(')')]
'abcdefg'
>>>
```

Comment: That's simpler, but also more brittle. It breaks if the string doesn't end with ')', which is bad.

Comment: @x10: It is not **more** brittle. It gives EXACTLY the same result as the OP's expression.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is good enough. You could make a function that accepts a string and returns it formatted.

Also, don't go with len(raw_text)-1, because that will fail on bad data like "Italy (BGN) ".

```
def get_code(str):
     return str[str.find('(')+1:str.find(')')]

formatted_text = get_code(raw_text)
```

Comment: Shadowing built-ins is a very bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('\((.{3})\)', 'Spain (BCN)').group(0)
'BCN'
```